# PUT request is getting mapped to GET request when deployed

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

I am facing a weird problem. In my Azure mobile app, I added a plain vanilla webapi controller with standard http verbs get, put etc. Now on my localhost everything is working fine. but when I deploy this to my azurewebsite. and call using Post man. the PUT request gets mapped to GET code. I tested using Postman, fiddler. 
I am sure I am missing sth, but couldn't figure it out, checked the route, tried multiple options, but just couldn't figure out. Same is true with DELETE and POST. below is the sample code[image]

```
[MobileAppController]
public class TestController : BaseController
{
    // GET: api/Test
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET: api/Test/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST: api/Test
    [Route("api/test")]
    public async Task<string> Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return "post: " + value;
    }

    // PUT: api/Test/5
    [Route("api/test/{id}")]
    public async Task<string> Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return "put: " + value;
    }

    // DELETE: api/Test/5
    [Route("api/test/{id}")]
    public async Task<string> Delete(int id)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return "delete: " + id;
    }
```

Comment: As I known, there is nothing wrong with your ApiController, have you tried to specify the HTTP method (**AcceptVerbs**, **HttpGet**, **HttpPut**, etc.) with your action to isolate this issue? Additionally, the endpoint in your screenshot and the response have no relation with your ApiController code, could you update your question?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing routing via WebAPI and routing via Mobile Apps, and they are conflicting.  Pick one.  For this application, I'd suggest removing the MobileAppController attribute and just going with the WebAPI routing.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, but the issue remains same

Comment: Holy crap!!! I found the issue, when I am using Postman, my url is "http" and any POST/PUT/DELETE request gets mapped to GET. and if I change it to "https" everything just works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are making request via SSL i.e. your url should be starting from https.

when I was using Postman, my url was starting with "http" and any POST/PUT/DELETE request gets mapped to GET. and if I change it to "https" everything just works as expected.

Comment: Based on your `TestController.cs`, requests with https or http could work as expected on my side via Postman.

Comment: it works same on my localhost, but not once I deployed to azure web site